# using LIKE operator in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want search companies from my company table when i give company name...here am using like operator

eg: saravana stores

it gives the result saravana stores texttiles,saravana stores thanga maligai,etc(which is contained with saravana stroes...coz of using `LIKE` operator)

Now my problem is when i give **lcd projectors** in the companyname, also want to fetch the records which are contained with the only **projector** word...but like operator gave the results with the 'lcd projector'

am making clear?

Comment: You can make use of `or` in your query...

Comment: you should google "like mysql" at least before posting

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
WHERE (name LIKE '%saravana%' OR name LIKE '%stores%')
```

This has two disadvantages:

- It can't use an index so it will be slow.
- It can give you matches you don't want like 'bestorest' matches '%stores%'.

You might want to use a [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) instead. You could also consider an external engine such as [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want proper fultext search, I highly recommend trying Lucene or Sphinx.
I know it would get a little complicated, but it's worth it for the end result.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Byers is right.
To get more efficiency
After query dividing to words you can modify search input to get word base and unify searching to get smth lika:
`WHERE (name LIKE '%sarava%' OR name LIKE '%stor%')`